# What is the purpose of using writeSelectedRows method in itextpdf?

Tags: itextpdf

I am using code like this:

```
upperTable.writeSelectedRows(1, -1,40,734,cb);
```

I am new in `ItextPdf`. What purpose of using `writeSelectedRows` method?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose is to write a `PdfPTable` at absolute positions.

When you create a `PdfPTable`, the most common way to add it to a `Document` is:

```
document.add(table);
```

However, there are cases where you can't use this. For instance: of you want to add a table as a header in a page event. In that case you'll use `writeSelectedRows`.

In your case, you adding the complete table minus the first row at coordinates `x=40;y=734` to the `PdfContentByte` object `cb`.

All of this and much more is explained here: http://developers.itextpdf.com